# Back to top button without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a button "Back to top" with javascript. My code (which I found on StackOverflow) does not work when I click the button nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
     <button type="button" id="backtotop_js">To the top</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
     document.getElementById('backtotop_js').onclick = function () {
        scrollTo(document.documentElement, 0, 1250);
     };
     function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
         var start = element.scrollTop,
             change = to - start,
             currentTime = 0,
             increment = 20;

         var animateScroll = function(){        
             currentTime += increment;
             var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
             element.scrollTop = val;
             if(currentTime < duration) {
                 setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
             }
         };
         animateScroll();
     }

     Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if(t < 1) 
           return c/2*t*t + b;
        t--;
        return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
     };
```

(I'm using Chrome and Firefox)

Where's the mistake?

Comment: scrollTo is a complicated process, only use it if you are intending to scroll a specific element. But if you want to scroll to top, just go to position 0.

Comment: `window` already has a method `scrollTo`. You probably shouldn't call your own function that.

Comment: Personally, I would use an old school anchor, no JS or anything. <a id="#header">Go To Top</a>. If must use JS just put ->  window.scrollTo(0,0);

Comment: @Rudie Sorry but I did not understand what I have to correct ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will make the scroll to top without animation in vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById('backtotop_js').onclick = function () {    
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

EDIT:
changed document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] to document.documentElement as per Rudie's comment below.

Comment: Some browsers have `document.documentElement` as the scroll container, instead of `document.body`. They all understand `window.scrollTo(x, y)` though.

Comment: If you want animation you can play with setTimeout to decrease gradually document.documentElement.scrollTop value to 0.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SzWHp/ - working here. Probably, you need to put your JS next to the closing body tag.

Comment: @vitkon It works! I fixed by putting the js code after the </body> tag. Thank you :)

Comment: should be just **before** `</body>`

Comment: @vitkon Sometimes it's `body`, sometimes it's `documentElement`. I don't think your solution will always work. You should set both `scrollTop`s. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Definition and Usage (of document.document.Element)

The documentElement property returns the documentElement of a document, as an Element object.

For HTML documents the returned object is the HTML element.

Note: If the HTML element is missing, the return value is null.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp

you shoud scroll not the html element but instead the body... as vikton was giving an example.

Comment: This should be a comment except that it isn't helpful.

Comment: And it's not true. This depends on the browsers. Some use `documentElement`, others use `body`.